# Cannot find module 'sonar-request' from 'api.js' when I run npm run test

Tags: node.js, testing, npm, sonarqube

When I run tests on my Sonarqube plugin, if a class call to the api, it returns an error but when there is no call to the api, it works great. 
Here is the error:

```
FAIL  src\main\js\__tests__\Cards-test.js
Test suite failed to run

Cannot find module 'sonar-request' from 'api.js'

  at Resolver.resolveModule (node_modules\jest-resolve\build\index.js:151:17)
  at Object.<anonymous> (src\main\js\api.js:176:81)
  at Object.<anonymous> (src\main\js\components\Cards.js:2:38)
```

How can I correct this error?

Comment: Please add the error message as text, don't add a picture of it.

Answer (score 1):

From the error message, it looks like `api.js` is part of your own coding (not a dependency).

You reference a `sonar-request` module on your computer which, according to your error message, does not exist. Usually, you would need to `npm install` it. But there is no such module on the [registry](https://www.npmjs.com/package/sonar-request) (at the time of this posting)

Please check your `api.js` file for the mentioned require statement (you will find it on line 176).

Comment: I am trying to test my Sonarqube plugin following this example : [link](https://github.com/SonarSource/sonar-custom-plugin-example). And they use the api.js file to request a web service. It works great until I test the class, and it shows me this error!